# What Ubuntu system should I download to usb flash drive

Tags: system-installation, system-requirements

I have a older Hewett Packard business laptop with windows xp as OS. What Ubuntu OS can I download onto a usb flash drive to use to install on the laptop?

Comment: I would recommend that if your computer came installed with Windows XP, using Ubuntu 12.04 or less, as your hardware may be of less quality

Comment: something like ubuntu mate would probally be better, I wouldn't use an older version as often you get better dirvers with newer versions

Comment: @DavidCole Ubuntu does not increase into an OS that needs more power as much as Windows does. A system running XP is more than likely to have 15.04 running smoothly. The issue here is the "usb flash drive". That might need a less memory consuming version like xUbuntu or lUbuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu and Xubuntu both work on lower spec devices than Ubuntu.
Check out these pages to see if your computer meet their minimum specs:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/